# JSON pattern recognition

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Suppose I have a JSON request body `req1`, and it resulted in a JSON response `resp1`, some of whose key-values are identical to those in `req1`. Now suppose I have another JSON request `req2`, and I want to construct a JSON response `resp2` which is a duplicate of `resp1`, but in which the common keys have their values replaced by the values from `req2`.

What strategy might be used to tackle this?

As a concrete example, suppose `req1` is this:

```
{"Name":"Alan"}
```

And suppose this is `resp1`:

```
{"output":{"Name":"Alan", "Cat": "12"}}
```

Note that `"Name":"Alan"` appears in both.

If `req2` is this:

```
{"Name":"Bancorp"}
```

Then I'd like to create `resp2` from `resp1` like this:

```
{"output":{"Name":"Bancorp", "Cat": "12"}}
```

Crucially, the document structure of `req*` and `resp*` *are not known in advance*, and the only knowledge is that the structure of `req1` and `req2` are similar, and likewise for `resp1` and `resp2`.

In other words, I'm looking for a flexible pattern-recognition that will "learn" from an initial `req1`/`resp1` pair by identifying fields that occurred in both, and then be able to respond to future `req*` inputs by making the proper substitutions to a copy of `resp1`.

Is this something which already exists? If not, how might it be implemented in `JSON.Net`?

Comment: if you deserialize your json into an object, do whatever you need to do, and then, serialize it again? wouldn't be easier?

Answer (score 0):

I would deserialize your requests into separate objects first. You could then use reflection to get a list of all the properties of each object and filter the results to only show the common properties.

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Once you have your list of properties that you need in the response object, you can create a new `ExpandoObject` and dynamically add the properties and corresponding values that you need.

```
dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
x.NewProp = string.Empty;
```

Once you're done, you can serialize this response object back to JSON.